# wait until scrollToRowAtIndexPath is done in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a `UITableView` with more cells than fit on screen. When I get a notification from my data model I want to jump to a specific row and show a very basic animation.

My code is:

```
 func animateBackgroundColor(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {        
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        NSLog("table should be at the right position")
        if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? BasicCardCell {
            var actColor = cell.backgroundColor
            self.manager.vibrate()
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() }, completion: {
                _ in

                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { cell.backgroundColor = actColor }, completion: { _ in
                        self.readNotificationCount--
                        if self.readNotificationCount >= 0 {
                            var legicCard = self.legicCards[indexPath.section]
                            legicCard.wasRead = false
                            self.reloadTableViewData()
                        } else {
                            self.animateBackgroundColor(indexPath)
                        }
                })
            })
        }
    }
}    

func cardWasRead(notification: NSNotification) {
    readNotificationCount++
    NSLog("\(readNotificationCount)")

        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? [String : AnyObject], let index = userInfo["Index"] as? Int {

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: index), atScrollPosition: .None, animated: true)

                self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
                NSLog("table should scroll to selected row")
            }
            self.animateBackgroundColor(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: index))
        }
}
```

I hoped that the dispatch_sync part would delay the execution of my `animateBackgroundColor` method until the scrolling is done. Unfortunately that is not the case so that `animateBackgroundColor` gets called when the row is not visible yet -> `cellForRowAtIndexPath` `returns nil` and my animation won't happen. If no scrolling is needed the animation works without problem.

Can anyone tell my how to delay the execution of my `animateBackgroundColor` function until the scrolling is done?

Thank you very much and kind regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delaying animation does not seem to be a good solution for this since `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` animation duration is set based on distance from current list item to specified item. To solve this you need to execute animateBackgroudColor after `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` animation is completed by implementing `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` UITableViewDelegate method. The tricky part here is to get indexPath at which tableview did scroll. A possible workaround:

```
var indexPath:NSIndexpath?

func cardWasRead(notification: NSNotification) {
readNotificationCount++
NSLog("\(readNotificationCount)")

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? [String : AnyObject], let index = userInfo["Index"] as? Int{

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

            self.indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: index)
            self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(self.indexPath, atScrollPosition: .None, animated: true)

            self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

            NSLog("table should scroll to selected row")
        }

    }

}

func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.animateBackgroundColor(self.indexPath)
    indexPath = nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

I have two problems with your solution.
1: when I am already displaying the right cells no scrolling will happen so the scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation method won't be called and the animation will not happen.
2: when I just scroll around the scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation method gets called and the animation will happen even if it shouldn't.

Why do you think that delaying the animation is not a good solution? What I woult like is to see the scrolling and as soon as I've reached the right cell it should start the animation.

Comment: 1: To solve that you must get visible cells by using `tableViews.visibleCells()` and then check if you need to scroll at all or just animate. 2:  scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation will be called only when scrolling programmatically and not by swiping

Answer (score 0):

Here are my solution

1) Create a .swift file, and copy code below into it:

```
typealias SwagScrollCallback = (_ finish: Bool) -> Void 

class UICollectionViewBase: NSObject, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    static var shared = UICollectionViewBase()

    var tempDelegate: UIScrollViewDelegate?
    var callback: SwagScrollCallback?

    func startCheckScrollAnimation(scroll: UIScrollView, callback: SwagScrollCallback?){
        if let dele = scroll.delegate {
            self.tempDelegate = dele
        }
        self.callback = callback
        scroll.delegate = self
    }
    func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        callback?(true)
        if let dele = self.tempDelegate {
            scrollView.delegate = dele
            tempDelegate = nil
        }
    }
}

extension UICollectionView {

    func scrollToItem(at indexPath: IndexPath, at scrollPosition: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition, _ callback: SwagScrollCallback?){
        UICollectionViewBase.shared.startCheckScrollAnimation(scroll: self, callback: callback)
        self.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: scrollPosition, animated: true)
    }

}
```

2) Example:

```
@IBAction func onBtnShow(){

        let index = IndexPath.init(item: 58, section: 0)
        self.clv.scrollToItem(at: index, at: .centeredVertically) { [weak self] (finish) in

            guard let `self` = self else { return }

            // Change color temporarily
            if let cell = self.clv.cellForItem(at: index) as? MyCell {
                cell.backgroundColor = .yellow
                cell.lbl.textColor = .red
            }


            // Reset
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                self.clv.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

3) My github code example: [github here](https://github.com/kieuquangloc147/UICollectionViewScrollExtention)

Answer (score -3):

I has similar problem. I just do this.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2,delay:0.0,options: nil,animations:{
          self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(self.indexPath!, atScrollPosition: .Middle, animated: true)},
                        completion: { finished in UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations:{
                            self.animateBackgroundColor(self.indexPath)})})}
```